# Trying to VBA Script some embedded if commands

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

What I am trying to do is get my macro to search the data in Column "E".  If the cell value contains "**string**", then I would like to offset by one column to the left, verify if, in the new selected cell, cell value contains "". If the new selected cell value is "" then background color is 19, if it contains "*" then background color is -4142.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Sub Set_Background_Color ()

    lRow = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set MR = Range("E2:E" & lRow)
    For Each cell In MR
    If cell.Value = "X" Then cell.Offset(, -1).Interior.ColorIndex = 19

    Next

End Sub
```

I can't seem to figure out how to embed a new If statement after the Offset and before the .Interior.ColorIndex

I have tried this mess but you will see immediately that it does not work.

```
If cell.Value = "X" Then
    ElseIf cell.Offset(, -1).Value = "" Then cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 19
    Else: cell.Interior.ColorIndex = -4142
```

Any help is greatly apreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So close!

```
Sub Set_Background_Color ()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim MR As Range
    Dim cel As Range
    lRow = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set MR = Range("E2:E" & lRow)
    For Each cel In MR
        If cel.Value = "string" Then
            If cel.Offset(, -1).Value = "" Then
                cel.Offset(, -1).Interior.ColorIndex = 19
            ElseIf cel.Offset(, -1).Value = "*" Then
                cel.Offset(, -1).Interior.ColorIndex = -4142
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so very much!  Works like a charm.  I felt I was getting close but I just couldn't get there.

Answer (score 0):

If by `contains "*"` you mean "has any content" then:

```
If cell.Value = "X" Then
    cell.Interior.ColorIndex = IIf(Len(cell.Offset(0, -1).Value) = 0, 19, xlNone)
End If
```